# Move UITextField in UIView that has constraints

Tags: swift, xcode, uiview, uitextfield, constraints

I am making an app that the use can input their car info into. I need the UITextFields to move up so they are not covered by the keyboard. I did this with this code.

```
func textFieldDidBeginEditing(_ textField: UITextField)
{
    if make==textField
    {
        self.infoContainer.frame = self.infoContainer.frame.offsetBy(dx: 0, dy:-50)
    }
    if model==textField
    {
        self.infoContainer.frame = self.infoContainer.frame.offsetBy(dx: 0, dy:-75)
    }
    if color==textField
    {
        self.infoContainer.frame = self.infoContainer.frame.offsetBy(dx: 0, dy:-100)
    }
}
```

Which worked great until I added constraints to to the UIView *infoContainer. then it would only work once. Like if I clicked on Make it would move up -50, or if I clicked on color it would move up -100. But after that one time it will not move again. Like if I clicked on Make it would move up -50, but then if I would click Color it will not move to -100. So then I tried doing it changing the constraints.

```
func textFieldDidBeginEditing(_ textField: UITextField)
    {
        if make==textField
        {
            infoContainer.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

            self.view.addSubview(infoContainer)

            let leadingConstraint = infoContainer.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.leadingAnchor)
            let trailingConstraint = infoContainer.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.trailingAnchor)
            let topConstraint = infoContainer.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.topAnchor, constant: -50)
            let bottomConstraint = infoContainer.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.bottomAnchor, constant: -50)

            initialConstraints.append(contentsOf: [leadingConstraint,trailingConstraint,topConstraint,bottomConstraint])

            NSLayoutConstraint.activate(initialConstraints)
        }
        if model==textField
        {
            infoContainer.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

            self.view.addSubview(infoContainer)

            let leadingConstraint = infoContainer.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.leadingAnchor)
            let trailingConstraint = infoContainer.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.trailingAnchor)
            let topConstraint = infoContainer.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.topAnchor, constant: -75)
            let bottomConstraint = infoContainer.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.bottomAnchor, constant: -75)

            initialConstraints.append(contentsOf: [leadingConstraint,trailingConstraint,topConstraint,bottomConstraint])

            NSLayoutConstraint.activate(initialConstraints)
        }
        if color==textField
        {
            infoContainer.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

            self.view.addSubview(infoContainer)

            let leadingConstraint = infoContainer.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.leadingAnchor)
            let trailingConstraint = infoContainer.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.trailingAnchor)
            let topConstraint = infoContainer.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.topAnchor, constant: -100)
            let bottomConstraint = infoContainer.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.bottomAnchor, constant: -100)

            initialConstraints.append(contentsOf: [leadingConstraint,trailingConstraint,topConstraint,bottomConstraint])

            NSLayoutConstraint.activate(initialConstraints)
        }
    }
```

This worked a little bit better. If I clicked on Make it moved up -50, and then model moved up -75, and then Color moved up -100. But then it will not move back down, like if I clicked back on Make it will not move back down to -50. I even set Color to +50. When I clicked on color it would drop +50, and then when I would click on Make it would move up to -50, and Model would move it up -75. But if I would click color again, it will not move back down to +50. Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you add the constraints every move , and this with time makes the conflicts , so you need to add the constraints only once , and adjust the constant value of the constraint you want to move , instead do this

1- Add this code snippet inside `viewDidLoad`

```
var bottomConstraint:NSLayoutConstraint!
```

//

```
infoContainer.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
self.view.addSubview(infoContainer)
let leadingConstraint = infoContainer.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.leadingAnchor)
let trailingConstraint = infoContainer.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.trailingAnchor)
let topConstraint = infoContainer.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.topAnchor, constant: -50)
bottomConstraint = infoContainer.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.bottomAnchor, constant: -50)
initialConstraints.append(contentsOf: [leadingConstraint,trailingConstraint,topConstraint,bottomConstraint])
NSLayoutConstraint.activate(initialConstraints)
```

2-

```
func textFieldDidBeginEditing(_ textField: UITextField)
{
    if make == textField
    {
        self.bottomConstraint.constant = -50
    }
    if model == textField
    {
        self.bottomConstraint.constant = -75
    }
    if color == textField
    {
        self.bottomConstraint.constant = -100
    }

   self.view.layoutIfNeeded()

   // you can animate it to

   /*
    UIView.animate(withDuration:0.5) {
      self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
    } */
}
```

You can do the same with `topConstraint` if you wanted to